# Stopping all the Child Threads created by windows service that schedule multiple email services

Tags: c#, multithreading, email

I am writing one windows service that schedule multiple email services. These email services implemented using different classes. I am Scheduling this email services by using a System.Thread.Timer in Windows service startup by calling the schedule method implemented in our custom schedular.This schedular method will calculate the time for running the service using Tick Event of the System.Thread.Timer.

Comment: Can you show code of waiting thread? Do you block on something, or you do not create any thread and just waiting for timer ticks?

Comment: Search for `task canceltation`, `volatile bool`, `wait handle and *resetevent`, `backgroundworker`. All of them will allow you to "cancel" or terminate workload gracefully.

Comment: yes , i am just waiting for Timer ticks... Initialization of services will happen first time and this in turn initialize the timer object and no. of ticks(interval) will be calculated.